# How can I get the list of phrases to train with Dialoflow Api v2?

Tags: api, dialogflow-es

I need your help to get a list of the phrases that do not have an intention and need training.

[I want to get this list but through the api of dialogFlow v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIzKC.png)

I appreciate your help in advance
Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you're asking or what you're trying to do. Can you update your question to clarify what you mean, what you're trying to do, and, perhaps, provide some examples? Stack Overflow works best when you have a specific problem with what you're trying to do and can provide information about what isn't working. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API call for the purpose you are looking for. However, there are a few ways you can get the user conversation flow data: 
1. Use third-party solutions that record the conversation and give you an option to download them. I cannot recall but I have seen at least one such solution. 
2. Create your own backend and log-in system, and include conversation in the log. You can save all the conversations in your backend for later use.